# GitHub CLI - Get current version

Tags: git, github, github-cli

I'm trying to find a command that will show me the current running version of GH CLI.

Right now yes, there is only 1 version (1.0) but in the future, we are going to need to know what version is being run for debug purposes (I'm currently writing internal doc, so I would like to future proof it.)

Usually, command line elements have a `-v` element like `yarn -v`so you can know what is the current running version. But that doesn't seem to work with GH CLI.

So is there a way to get the current running GH CLI version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly, this doesn't seem to be documented, but it's just `gh version`

You can see the commands at https://github.com/cli/cli/tree/trunk/pkg/cmd

Comment: lol I had tried `gh help version`and it told me it did not exist.

Comment: (+1) FWIW there seem to be a few other [`Hidden: true`](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/v1.5.0/pkg/cmd/version/version.go#L15) commands e.g. [`gh ssh-key`](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1755).

Comment: Error: No such command "version". I must have the version that doesn't have version.

Answer (score 2):

The documented command is `gh --version`.

```
C:\etc>gh help
Work seamlessly with GitHub from the command line.

...

FLAGS
  --help      Show help for command
  --version   Show gh version
```

Output:

```
C:\etc>gh --version
gh version 1.5.0 (2021-01-21)
https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.5.0
```